# Laravel Sail does not create my project folder

Tags: laravel, macos, laravel-10, laravel-sail

I'm trying to set up a Laravel project using Sail on my Mac by following the instructions [here](https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/what-is-laravel-sail-and-how-to-get-started).

I've installed Docker. When I run the command...

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/devdojo-sail | bash
```

...everything appears to run correctly except that the devdojo-sail folder does not get created.

Here's the output:

```
latest: Pulling from laravelsail/php82-composer
Digest: <SHA>
Status: Image is up to date for laravelsail/php82-composer:latest

   _                               _
  | |                             | |
  | |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
  | |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
  | |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
  |______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|

   WARN  TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.

    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./devdojo-sail"
    Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
    Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
      - Downloading laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
      - Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6): Extracting archive
    Created project in /opt/devdojo-sail
    > @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    ...
    <PACKAGES DOWNLOADED AND INSTALLED HERE>
    ...

   INFO  Discovering packages.

      laravel/sail     ..........................................................     DONE
  laravel/sanctum     .......................................................     DONE
  laravel/tinker     ........................................................ DONE
  nesbot/carbon     .........................................................     DONE
  nunomaduro/collision ..................................................     DONE
  nunomaduro/termwind     ................................................... DONE
      spatie/laravel-ignition     ...............................................     DONE

    82 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
    > @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

   INFO  No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

    No security vulnerability advisories found
    > @php artisan key:generate --ansi

   INFO  Application key set successfully.

   INFO  Application ready! Build something amazing.

Sail scaffolding installed successfully.
   WARN  TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.

bash: line 17: cd: devdojo-sail: No such file or directory
bash: line 23: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory
bash: line 24: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Very weird, I do run that command on my WSL2 terminal and it works perfectly. I read the bash command (the URL) and it looks right

Comment: it's time to start debugging. Open composer.json and look for `sail`, see if it's there

Comment: @UnderDog Which composer.json? There's no devdojo-sail folder to look in.

Comment: `Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./devdojo-sail"` <<= that should have made a directory called `devdojo-sail`

Comment: @UnderDog That's my issue. The directory doesn't get created.

Comment: Laravel Herd is something especially made for Macs: https://herd.laravel.com/ , then you don't need Docker/Sail

Comment: Maybe this is the issue https://github.com/laravel/installer/issues/297